# Is there any work that specifically refutes the claims of Martin Luther in "The Jews and Their Lies"?

Tags: christianity, anti-semitism

Recently I learned about Martin Luther's anti-Jewish book, *The Jews and Their Lies* which makes all of the accusations of anti-Semetism against him make a lot more sense given that they're explcitly stated.

But one thing that I thought was interesting was that the concrete arguments he gives seem to be a fairly well built, if vitriolic example of the Christian polemic against the Jews. They seem to basically be the same ones used today, only without any restraint.

Unfortunately the only works I was able to find on this were more about its suggestions (like burning down Synagogues), its effects (Kristelnacht and possibly the Holocaust), but not about its arguments. It's been almost 500 years since it came out, so it seems like some learned Jew must have read it. Is there anywhere I can find a Jewish scholar having gone through that specific book and refute Luther's arguments?

I am not asking for discussion or  on this essay, only any possible Jewish answer that may have already been written at any time during the past 500 years.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Giddy and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works? Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: I'll second mbloch's welcome. That said, the site is for questions about Judaism, not about Jewish people. Does Luther's work concern itself with Judaism per se?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 

This question is why Luther ymach shemo is right/ not right according to Judaism. This is not a question about Tora

Comment: @msh210 On the Jews and their Lies is a Christian polemic at heart. It is one of the early works that had arguments that we see Christians making now.

Comment: @kouty for what purpose? I am not asking for discussion of this work. I am asking to be referred to something written on this. Is the request for a Jewish work on a given topic considered off topic?

Comment: I non-vote against closing the question.  I had not really known about Martin Luthor's writings against Jews and Judaism, so I'm curious about the answers to this question.

Comment: (re your comment addressed to me) I don't see how that answers my concern. It's a Christian polemic against *what*? If it's only against Jews, and not the religion per se, it's off topic on this site.

Comment: It's a request for Jewish writings on a specific topic. I am not asking for discussion of this polemic or commentary on it from any SE user. The only information I am asking for is any possible  Jewish writings on this specific essay by Martin Luther.

Comment: @msh210 It sounds from [the WP entry on this essay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Jews_and_Their_Lies) like its attacks are directed at least in part at Judaism, *per se*. It seems to me therefore that this is a question about discussions about Judaism and is therefore on-topic. That said, I wouldn't be optimistic about finding answers; what good would it do for rabbis to argue with an essay based on Christian theology and hateful opinions?

Comment: I have not read Luther's work. If the arguments are precursors to modern objections to Judaism, it might be worthwhile to isolate specific claims so that responses to them (and not to an entire text) might be found.

Comment: I'm more interested in responses to this specific work. The same arguments he made have been made in a more compelling and less hysterical form by later Christians, responses to which are easily found. At this point I may as well write the book myself.